# Having trouble with HEREDOC

Tags: php, heredoc

HEREDOC is eating my lunch. I understand that white spaces are important to avoid. I don't think white spaces are my problem.  Below is an example of what is working and what is not working.

**THIS WORKS**

```
$StringVariable =<<<EOT
<form method="post" action="PHP_FILENAME.PHP">
EOT;
```

**THIS DOES NOT**

```
$StringVariable =<<<EOT
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
EOT;
```

Does not work means the page does not load...blank screen

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have `<?php ... ?>` tags inside HEREDOC. This should work:

```
$a = htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$StringVariable =<<<EOT
  <form method="post" action="$a">
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use HEREDOCs with <? and ?> in it. It causes problems. Write this instead:

```
$StringVariable = '<form method="post" action="<' . '?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?' . '>">';
```

Comment: I'm using PHP. I copied this directly into my code and I still get the blank screen when loaded.  If I comment out '//' the page loads.